# C++ copying another file

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

i was wondering how to use c++ ifstream/ofstream to copy a file and save it as another name.

this is as far as i got. I know how to get the file, its just that i don't know how to copy that file and save it as a different name.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
    namespace std;
int main()
    {
    ofstream
    ifstream
    cout << "enter your file you want to copy"<< endl;
    cin >> input_file_name;
    in_file.open(input_file_name);
    if (!in_file)
    {
    cout <<" there is no such file"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
    cout <<" enter the name you want to save this copy file"<<endl;
    cin >> output_file_name;
    out_file.open(output_file_name);
    if (!out.file)
    {
    cout<<"file is not available"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
    in_file.close();
    out_file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`rdbuf` with overloaded `<<` is standard way to go.

```
  ifstream src;
  ofstream dst;

  src.open("from", ios::in | ios::binary);
  dst.open("toto", ios::out | ios::binary);
  dst << src.rdbuf();

  src.close();
  dst.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy a file and save it on another file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream file1(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream file2(argv[2]);
    std::string line;
    if (file1.good() && file2.good()) {
        while (getline(file1, line)) {
            file2 << line;
            file2 << '\n';
        }
    }
    file1.close();
    file2.close();
}
```

Comment: curious what your code would do with binary (say, compressed) file(s)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux like a JPEG you say? Something tells me that the Filesystem takes care of that...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Really? Care to tell me what would be a "line" in the JPEG? What would "getline(file1, line)" call return?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux would have to test it to be sure, and check what `getline()` does specifically. Good thing the post didn't asked about compressed files, but still, something tells me that the filesystem would "unravel" the compression, but it's just an hypothesis. Worst case the whole JPEG is one single line?... what do you think will happen?

Comment: The file system will almost certainly **NOT** uncompress anything.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to read a character at a time and write said character to the output stream.  There's a get() overload which accepts a streambuf output variable that would work.  You could also use the example on cplusplus.com rdbuf documentation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/rdbuf/

Answer (score 0):

This code below should give you a sense of what you want to do.

> There are few things you should keep in mind, for example:
>
> - is the path of the file giving to read is valid?
> - or do you want to save the data from an output file if that file exists, before pushing new data?.

You could test this code by just creating a file into your desktop or any location, just change the `filePath` and `destinationPath` variables then run the code. (c++ 11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> readFromFile(const char *filePath) {
    vector<string> container;
    ifstream obj(filePath); // automatically our file would be open
    if (obj.is_open()) { // we check anyways
        string line = "";
        while(getline(obj, line)) {
            if (!line.empty()) // prevent us to insert empty line into our vector
             container.push_back(line);
        }
        obj.close(); // close after we finish reading to avoid corruption
    }
    return container;
}

bool pipingToDestination(vector<string>data, const char *filePath) {
    std::filebuf fb; fb.open(filePath,std::ios::out); // open the file
    ostream obj(&fb);
    if (!data.empty() && fb.is_open()) { // make sure we have some data && the file file is open to write
        for (string x: data) { // c++11
            obj << x << endl; 
        }
        fb.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    string filePath = "/Users/lamar/Desktop/testFile.txt";
    vector<string> data = readFromFile(filePath.c_str());
    
    cout << "File has passed data into container ... \n";
    
    for(string x: data) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Creating destination file \n";
    string destinationPath = "/Users/lamar/Desktop/destFile.txt";
    cout << "has piped data into file " << boolalpha << pipingToDestination(data, destinationPath.c_str());
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is not the only way to do this, but this code should put you on a direction